# Access DataTemplate controls in code behind

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I have problem with this code:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lbInvoice" ItemsSource="{Binding ocItemsinInvoice}">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="btnInvoiceItem">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ToggleButton x:Name="btnInvoiceQuantity" Content="{Binding Quantity}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item.ItemName}" Width="175" Padding="7,5,0,0"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ToggleButton>
            <Popup x:Name="popQuantity" Closed="popQuantity_Closed" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=btnInvoiceQuantity}" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked,ElementName=btnInvoiceQuantity}">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbUnitPrice" Text="Unit Price"/>
                        <Button x:Name="btnClosePopup" Click="btnClosePopup_Click">
                    </Grid>
            </Popup>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

In code behind in `btnClosePopup` click event I can't access to popup to close it and do some other changes on it.

I have tried to use `FindName()` method but it doesn't work for me

```
var template = lbInvoice.Template;
var myControl = (Popup)template.FindName("popQuantity", lbInvoice);
```

Please can you help and tell me how do I access to controls that inside DataTemplate in code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already to `Open/Close` this `Popup` in this line:

```
IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=btnInvoiceQuantity}"
```

As an alternative answer from @dkozl, you can close the `Popup` in such a way:

```
<Popup x:Name="popQuantity" 
       IsOpen="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=btnInvoiceQuantity}">

    <Grid Width="200" Height="200" Background="Gainsboro">
        <TextBlock Text="Unit Price" />

        <ToggleButton x:Name="btnClosePopup" 
                      IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsChecked, ElementName=btnInvoiceQuantity}"
                      Content="Close"
                      Width="100" 
                      Height="30" />
    </Grid>
</Popup>
```

Or you can directly specify a property `IsOpen` of Popup:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="btnClosePopup"
               IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsOpen, ElementName=popQuantity}" ... />
```

But in this case at the background color of `Button` will be in state of `IsChecked="True"`. To avoid this, without creating a new Template for your Control, you can use a system style of flat button:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="btnClosePopup"
              Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ToggleButtonStyleKey}}" ... />
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to do it in code behind and if you change `Popup.IsOpen` in code it won't appear again as you'll lose you binding. You need to set `IsChecked` on `ToggleButton` to false and you can do it with `EventTrigger`

```
<Button Content="Close" x:Name="btnClosePopup">
   <Button.Triggers>
      <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
         <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
               <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName=" btnInvoiceQuantity" Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsChecked">
                  <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame Value="False" KeyTime="0:0:0"/>
               </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
         </BeginStoryboard>
      </EventTrigger>
   </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```