# access controls present in data template from code behind

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

I  have  the  following XAML code..

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DataTemplate1" >
        <Border BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="1" Height="150" Width="500" >
            <Grid Width="500" Height="150" Background="White" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.5*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="2.5*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>

                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Source="/Images/notav.jpg" Margin="0,5,4,4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding PRICE}" TextWrapping="Wrap"  Grid.Column="1"  Width="350"  Foreground="Black" Height="60" Margin="30,85,20,-10"/>

                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding ITMNAME }" FontSize="22" TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Column="1"   Name="txtITMNAME" Foreground="DarkBlue" Width="500"  Height="130"  Margin="30,40,20,-10"/>

                <c4f:RoundButton   Grid.Column="2" Name="btntick" Click="btntick_Click" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="LightGray" Foreground="DarkGray" Margin="10,20,45,10"   />

            </Grid>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

<ListBox Height="Auto" Name="lstbxmanual" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate1 }" Width="475" Margin="4,148,0,5" Background="White"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Grid.RowSpan="2">
</ListBox>
```

I  have  to  access  round button  at  code  behind ,to  change  its  background  property...

```
private void btntick_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    btntick. //not  able  to  access...
}
```

I have gone through following stackoverflow questions..

[Access DataTemplate controls in code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22731658/access-datatemplate-controls-in-code-behind)

[MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb613579.aspx)

it  seems  to  be  not  relevant  to  my  requirement..
please  help  me in  this  regard...

Comment: I answered a question recently that was like this question. To get a button inside a `DataTemplate` and change it's properties in code by using `FrameworkTemplate.FindName` Method. Check it here and let me know if it was what you wanted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34117944/listbox-items-return-string-when-datatemplate-is-button

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:** Use `x:Name` instead of `Name`.

**Solution 2:** Here is the an alternate way too.

You can cast the event sender object:

```
private void btntick_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    RoundButton rdbtn = sender as RoundButton;
    //rdbtn.BackColor
}
```

Comment: solution  2  wont  work  if   we  want  to  access  all  controls  inside the  listbox...please  provide a    flexible  solution...

Answer (score 0):

please try, `x:Name` in place of Name it will be accessible from your code behind file.

```
<c4f:RoundButton   Grid.Column="2" x:Name="btntick" Click="btntick_Click" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="25" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Background="LightGray" Foreground="DarkGray" Margin="10,20,45,10"   />



private void btntick_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       btntick.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;                    
    }
```

Good Luck.