# how to change background color of button in UWP Apps in c# ?

Tags: c#, button, colors, background, win-universal-app

I have a simple and I need to change colors of my buttons every second in that . I use this code `btnBlue.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Blue)` But it doesn't contain my custom color that I have use in xaml like `#FF30B3DD` !
So what should I do ? can anybody help me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In universal windows apps, how to change the background color of a button using xaml and databinding if a property in the view model changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34251318/in-universal-windows-apps-how-to-change-the-background-color-of-a-button-using)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use `Color.FromArgb()` to define a custom color in code:

```
btnBlue.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(255, 48, 179, 221));
```

Alternatively, you can define the color in XAML in advance as a resource:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BlueColor" Color="#FF30B3DD" />
</Page.Resources>
```

You can then reference the resource from the code:

```
btnBlue.Background = (SolidColorBrush)Resources["BlueColor"];
```

Comment: Thanks very much bro :)