# Changing ellipse fill color inside a button

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to change the ellipse fill color to green when the button is enabled.

```
   <Button x:Name="btn_Kaart2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" IsEnabled="False">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse_2" 
                         Height="35"
                         Stroke="Black"
                         Fill="Red"
                         Margin="-300,440,0,0"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

Normally I would use `ellipse_2.Fill = "Color"` but that doesn't work, program can't find `ellipse_2`

Comment: Could you provide the code where you're trying to change the colour?

Comment: `ellipse_2` != `elliplse_2`

Comment: @blas3nik Currently I just have a method with a if clause that checks if the button is enabled or not and that method is called out when the UserControl is loaded.

Comment: @Albireo Sorry thats just a typo.

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34117944/listbox-items-return-string-when-datatemplate-is-button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a databinding with `RelativeSource` to get this without any additional code

```xml
<Button x:Name="btn_Kaart2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" IsEnabled="False">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Ellipse x:Name="ellipse_2" 
                Height="35"
                Margin="-300,440,0,0"
                Stroke="Black">
            <Ellipse.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Ellipse">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="red"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Button}}" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="green"></Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Ellipse.Style>
            </Ellipse>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

**It's important that the `Ellipse` itself has no `Fill` attribute**.
You can try this by changing the `IsEnabled` value in the *.xaml and the color should change immediately in the designer.

Comment: Well, that should work, but for some reason it won't. I'll mark this as answered and try to implement the button in a other way.

Comment: My bad again, forgot to remove the Fill property. Thanks!