# in wpf access stack panel from nested node in treeview

Tags: c#, wpf

I want in the loop for each Node be able to change Background in Stack Panel when the Node accessed and after it left set Background to Transparent again.

My problem: I do not know how to access to Stack Panel to change BackGround from code behind.
I would appreciate any help

Here is my code:
TreeView Control

```
<TreeView Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ListOfNodes}"
                                                    Background="Linen" Margin="0,0,0,-0">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="True"/>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Name="HDT_node" DataType="Node" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    MouseLeftButtonDown="btnTreeItemStartPlay"
                                    Background="Transparent">
                <Image Source="{Binding Path=image.Source}" Width="30" Height="30"
                                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                     MouseEnter="ZoomStart" MouseLeave="ZoomStop" />
            </StackPanel>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

Class Node:

```
public class Node
{
    public Image image { get; set; }

    public List<Node> Children { get; set; }

    public Node()
    {
    }

    public Node(Image imageIn, int orderIndexIn)
    {
        image = imageIn;
        Children = new List<Node>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34117944/listbox-items-return-string-when-datatemplate-is-button

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to access `StackPanel` within `DataTemplate`. However you can still use [`VisualTreeHelper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper(v=vs.110).aspx) to iterate over visual tree on runtime and do whatever you want to do.

Before doing that use [WPF Visual Tree Visualizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409789.aspx) to familiarize yourself with Visual Tree that you have. Afterward start from `TreeView` and iterate over children to get desired child. As based on your templates, visual tree varies.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helped.

Comment: @Yefim if that was what you are looking for, don't forget to accept it