# C# UWP TextBlock text change in Button Style programatically

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, windows-10, uwp-xaml

I have a button with Resource style. I would like to change Text of TextBlock in Button Content. I didn't find any solution.

Any idea?

```
<Style x:Key="NavigationLogoutButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}">
<Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
<Setter Property="Height" Value="48"/>
<Setter Property="Width" Value="NaN"/>
<Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="48"/>
<Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Logout"/>
<Setter Property="Content">
    <Setter.Value>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="48" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <FontIcon Grid.Column="0" FontSize="16" Glyph="&#xE1E0;" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" Text="!!!TEXT HERE PROGRAMATICALLY!!!" Foreground="{StaticResource MainColorBrush}" FontSize="13" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" Text="{StaticResource LogoutButtonText}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ListBox items return string, when DataTemplate is Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34117944/listbox-items-return-string-when-datatemplate-is-button)

Comment: Not duplicate. Because I am not using DataTemplate, just Content property.

Comment: What do you mean by programaticaly? Enable the content Binding of a regular button? what is it you are trying to achieve exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a hack, change the line:

```
<TextBlock Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" Text="!!!TEXT HERE PROGRAMATICALLY!!!" Foreground="{StaticResource MainColorBrush}" FontSize="13" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

to

```
<TextBlock Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" Text="{Binding Tag}" Foreground="{StaticResource MainColorBrush}" FontSize="13" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

And set the `Tag` property of your Button in code.

The proper way to do it would be declare new `DependencyProperty` type string of a CustomButton which inherits from Button. Then apply the Style to the new CustomButton type. Bind the `Text` property to the newly created `DependencyProperty`

Comment: Thanks :) I am so stupid :D I made a custom button with SubContent property :)